# how can we push ".db" into emulator?

Tags: android

Can we push a database that is created by some ide like **sqlitestudio** and push it into our emulator for **app uses**?
is there any way to push our ".db" format into andriod emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to ship you application by creating database outside , 
these are good tutorial to add database to your application , and these are few good tutorials to start with

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/database-crud-tutorial-for-android/

http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

If your device is an emulator or is a physical device connected thru USB, you can use this command-line:

```
adb push c:\local_path\myfile.db /path_on_the_device/myfile
```

Comment: is path_on_th_device same for all devices? Can you please give an practical example?

Comment: @ShirishHerwade No, the path depends on where you would like to push the file. And example is `adb push c:\tmp\file.txt /sdcard/tmp/file.txt`. I usually use that with emulators (which are rooted) or with my phone but it is rooted. You can have a look at this for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834241/how-to-use-adb-command-to-push-a-file-on-device-without-sd-card

Answer (score 2):

You better add db into assets and copy it into sd or internal storage.
Here is some code snippet for you

```
private void CopyFileFromAssets() {
    AssetManager asm = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = asm.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
    for(String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = asm.open(filename);
          //you can even create folder to put your file
          out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + filename);
          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Hope this can help

Comment: true, but it's better to push it directly in the app database folder - "/data/data/[rootpackage]/databases/"

Answer (score 0):

Go to file explorer - data - data - your pkg name - select database and click on push a file onto the device.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the db extension.

1.then select DDMS

2.then select emulator from device tab

3.move to data/data//databases

4.now push file into emulator using the top-right open in window.

5.Now run the app.

Thank you.