# How do I do like DataTable in Android-Java based application.

Tags: c#, java, android

I believed that DataTable which in C# is to hold data which we fetched from DB. I have application where I need to implement something similar in Android using Java. I need to save/hold the data which I fetched from DB for different activity. Can anyone suggest or share how do I achieve this.
I tried use ResulSet but ResultSet holds all the data meanwhile I want to get the filtered data where something like DataRow in C#.
Please help.

Comment: try creating your own object e.g. http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/java-creating-data-table-in-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using eclipse then you can use SQlite Browser to store your database and then can push data base in ur device by going to Window->Open perspective->other->DDMS
[how can we push ".db" into emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242023/how-can-we-push-db-into-emulator)
and then u can apply queries on your database.
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out these three classes in SDK, It should do similar functionality.

1. [ResultSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/ResultSet.html)
2. [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)
3. [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and re-implemented the C# DataTable, DataRow stuff, since Cursors to a SQLiteDatabase don't write back changes to DB, afaik.