# How to use adb command to push a file on device without sd card

Tags: android, adb

How to push a file from computer to an Android device having no SD Card in it. I tried:

```
C:\anand>adb push anand.jpg /data/local
3399 KB/s (111387 bytes in 0.032s)

C:\anand>adb push anand.jpg /data/opt
3199 KB/s (111387 bytes in 0.034s)

C:\anand>adb push anand.jpg /data/tmp
3884 KB/s (111387 bytes in 0.028s)
```

Above commands to move a file `anand.jpg` to a device but I didn't get this `jpg` file in the device.
I didn't get any success result on `cmd` prompt, I only got:

```
3399 KB/s (111387 bytes in 0.032s).
```

Comment: Try `adb shell "cd /data/local && mkdir tmp"` then `adb push anand.jpg /data/local/tmp`. How do you check for the file on the device, with `adb shell`?

Comment: @RC i am using ls command to check the files. i got it atleast on the DDMS view on emulator.but still i didnt get it on the device. when i am trying "adb push" command it shows device not found for real device. but adb devices is showing the device.

Comment: I would stop the emulator, unplug the device, then after ensuring device is in debug mode, plug the device and retry

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: RC's suggestion worked in this variation for me: `adb shell "cd /sdcard && mkdir temp"` then `abd push x.apk /sdcard/temp"` I ended up with my file in the temp folder on my sdcard, and was able to flash from there.

Comment: I was having trouble and it turned out I was using wildcards in my local path. Apparently those aren't supported!

Answer (score 213, accepted):

From Ubuntu/Mac Terminal, the below command should work.

```
./adb push '/home/hardik.trivedi/Downloads/one.jpg' '/data/local/'
```

For `adb` v33 and above if you are getting a permission denied error, try what I tried. The following command and it works fine.
The only caveat is you might need to use `tmp` directory on such an emulator.

```bash
adb shell #Entering into shell
su #Super user mode
chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/ #Granting RWX access
exit
chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/ #Granting RWX access
exit
```

And then try

```
./adb push '/home/hardik.trivedi/Downloads/one.jpg' '/data/local/tmp/'
```

Comment: I am working on windows cmd prompt can u plz tell me in windows how to do it.

Comment: just remove './' and use simple adb or adb.exe. Make sure you are in platform-tools folder if you haven't set path for android.

Comment: i have set platform-tools in the path variable. one more thing the above push command we can run in cmd from any root/folder or from the location of JPG file.

Comment: To avoid all confusion, go to platform-tools folder and the execute this command. Also provide absolute path of your image which is stored in any of your drive. Avoid spaces between file names and folder other wise insert escape character before space. Moreover why are you not using DDMS of eclipse to push the file.

Comment: thanks HARDIK. i got it atleast on the DDMS view on emulator.. but still i didnt get it on the device. when i am trying "adb push" command it shows device not found for real device.

Comment: Can we do this without rooting the phone?

Comment: @HardikTrivedi: Are you saying that rooting is needed to use adb push in general, or for this particular file destination? I'm using adb push to write a file on the Android device's SD card on a non-rooted device.

Comment: To push command works for non rooted phone also, only /data folder is requires rooted user.

Comment: In Windows, be in the folder that contains adb.exe (unless you've included that in your PATH) and try: `adb "C:\path\to\file.jpg" /data/local/` That's how I pushed a zip to recovery recently.

Comment: For me, my data started in `/storage/emulated/0/`, that's where all my `Movies/` and `Pictures/` folders were.

Comment: For adb v33 and a Google store image this no longer works.

Comment: @SimonFeatherstone Hey bud!, I have updated my answer. I hope it works for you. Thanks for reporting :)

Comment: @HardikTrivedi ended up with a more complicated answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74788524/113012

Answer (score 60):

I did it using the `push` command, which has syntax:

```
adb push filename.extension /sdcard/0/
```

Example of copying directory, and sub-directory content:

```bash
adb push C:\my-location\data\. /storage/emulated/0/Android/data
```

> **Note** that `push` did just hang in latest platform-tools (`33.0.1`, at time of writing) for a certain amount of files, beside the `adb.exe` suddenly taking 5MB+ instead of 1.5MB, **hence I just did replace the `adb.exe` with one I had from `28.0.0` version of platform-tools** (I did not downgrade the entire platform-tools, because `adb.exe` is kind of stand-alone).
>
> I **don't** say there is any conspiracy around `data` folder,
>
> But my Samsung device puts limits on my USB file transfer, beside Android `v11+` not allowing access to `data` folder anymore, hence I needed above command to work with 100% speed (without hanging one hour for little more files).

Comment: just moved an mp3 file from mac osX to an android 5.0 device and I had to write the name of the file to be on the device, i.e. "adb push /file.mp3 /sdcard/fileOrOtherFileName.mp3 "

Answer (score 36):

Follow these steps :

go to Android Sdk then 'platform-tools' path on your Terminal or Console

(on mac, default path is : /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools)

To check the SDCards(External and Internal) installed on your device fire these commands :

- 1) **./adb shell** (hit return/enter)
- 2) **cd** -(hit return/enter)

now you will see the list of Directories and files from your android device
there you may find /sdcard as well as /storage

- 3) **cd /storage** (hit return/enter)
- 4) **ls** (hit return/enter)

you may see sdcard0 (generally sdcard0 is internal storage) and sdcard1 (if External SDCard is present)

- 5) **exit** (hit return/enter)

to come out of adb shell

- 6) **./adb push '/Users/SML/Documents/filename.zip'
  /storage/sdcard0/path_to_store/** (hit return/enter)

to copy file

Answer (score 12):

run below command firstly

```
adb root
adb remount
```

Then execute what you input previously

```bash
C:\anand>adb push anand.jpg /data/local
C:\anand>adb push anand.jpg /data/opt
C:\anand>adb push anand.jpg /data/tmp
```

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes you need the extension,

> adb push file.zip /sdcard/file.zip

Comment: I have LG Nexus 5 and you can't put external sdcard in it but a part of the internal memory behaves like it was an sdcard

In this case sdcard is just a directory at the root level

You can check it with calling 'adb shell'

When you are in the shell call 'ls' for directory listing

Answer (score 11):

After Trying all the answers this worked for me

Where I am Pushing a file on Desktop to Android Device (Redmi K20 pro) connected Over the air using adb.

This command pushes the file to the downloads folder on my phone

```
adb push ~/Desktop/notifications.drawio ./storage/emulated/0/Download
```

after running this if you get a permission denied error

try running these commands in order (which basically changes the directory permission)

```
adb shell

chmod 777 /data/local/tmp

exit
```

and then run try the `adb push` command

I have [documented this here](https://gist.github.com/maheshmnj/96ef373b2f63c99ecc63c8ab3ecdf4aa) feel free to share your views and help improve it.

Answer (score 10):

Try this to push in Internal storage.

**adb push my-file.apk ./storage/emulated/0/**

Works in One plus device, without SD card.

Comment: works on samsung

Answer (score 5):

My solution (example with a random mp4 video file):

1. Set a file to device:

   ```
   adb push /home/myuser/myVideoFile.mp4 /storage/emulated/legacy/
   ```
2. Get a file from device:

   ```
   adb pull /storage/emulated/legacy/myVideoFile.mp4
   ```

For retrieve the path in the code:

```
String myFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myVideoFile.mp4";
```

This is all. This solution doesn't give permission problems and it works fine.

Last point: I wanted to change the video metadata information. If you want to write into your device you should change the permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I've got a Nexus 4, that is without external storage. However Android thinks to have one because it mount a separated partition called "storage", mounted in "/storage/emulated/legacy", so try pushing there: `adb push anand.jpg /storage/emulated/legacy`

Comment: For my nexus 4 **/sdcard.file.zip** worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

As there are different paths for different versions. Here is a generic solution:

Find the path...

1. Enter `adb shell` in command line.
2. Then `ls` and Enter.

Now you'll see the files and directories of Android device. Now with combination of `ls` and `cd dirName` find the path to the Internal or External storage.

In the root directory, the directories names will be like `mnt, sdcard, emulator0,` etc

Example: `adb push file.txt  mnt/sdcard/myDir/Projects/`

Answer (score 1):

This might be the best answer you'll may read.
Setup Android Studio
Then just go to view & Open Device Explorer.
Right-click on the folder & just upload a file.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac: To push files via adb

```
adb push /Users/Downloads⁩/amazon.sdktester.json '/mnt/sdcard/amazon.sdktester.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write to system folders. With ADB you have root (admin) access so you see the system folders of which sdcard is one of them so to send a picture you could use

D:\Program Files\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb push am files\android sdk\adb.exe push *C:\Downloads\anand.jpg* /sdcard/pictures/

NB: C:\Downloads\anand.jpg replace with path and name to picture..

Answer (score 0):

Certain versions of android do not fire proper tasks for updating the state of file system.
You could trigger an explicit intent for updating the status of the file system.
(I just tested after being in the same OP's situation)

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///
```

(You could pass a specific filepath instead of  `file:///` like `file:///sdcard` )

Comment: I'd like to add specify something. I've been using this command for a while now but in a bit different format. `adb -s $device shell am broadcast -W android.intent.action.MEDIA_SEARCH`.  The `-s $device` is needed if you have more than one attached device.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an already removed SDCard still registered in Android.
So I longpressed the entry for my old SDCard under:

`Settings | Storage & USB`

and selected "Forget".

Afterwards a normal

`adb push myfile.zip /sdcard/`

worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To push all the files at your directory to the Android device use:

```
PS D:\myFiles> adb push . '/data/local/tmp/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb?hl=en#copyfiles), the following command is suggested.

```
adb push myfile.txt /sdcard/myfile.txt
```

Using `/sdcard` as the remote path also worked in Redmi Note 10 Pro.

---

If the `adb push` fails, try switching remote to one of the following paths.

```
/data/local
/data/local/tmp
/data/opt
/data/tmp
/mnt/sdcard
/sdcard
/sdcard/0
/storage/emulated/0
/storage/sdcard0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Galaxy S22u with Android 14, and if it matters, OneUI 6.0, and this series of Galaxy has *no slot for an SD card*, however, adb shows my device has /sdcard/... storage, where /sdcard is a link: sdcard -> **/storage/self/primary**.

In other words, I can "adb push file.xyz /sdcard/Zyx" where Zyx is a directory on my S22u, in reality, it's a directory at /storage/self/primary/Zyx.